# how to update firefox on redhat via yum

Tags: firefox, redhat, yum

I have firefox 3.0.12 on my redhat 5.8 and I'm trying to update it.
But, yum update firefox does not find and new version and keeps finding only 3.0.12
I have also tried updating yum itself.

I have also tried downloading firefox tgz, but I get a lot of dependency files missing. So going that route is very tedious and I'm finding it hard to download the dependent .so files.

How do I update using yum or is there a .rpm for firefox that I can download and install(I did not find one on the mozilla website)

Comment: Since your system is still at redhat 5.8 and is not at 5.9, have you not been updating the system? Is the system subscribed to a Red Hat update server/repo?

Comment: Is it a problem if I don't upgrade to 5.9? Unfortunately it is a company thing and I cannot move to 5.9

Comment: does have to be yum or anything else ?

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

If `yum upgrade firefox` does not report any possible updates, you probably do not have proper channels enabled (you are not subscribed into these). You should see `rhel-x86_64-server-5` (depends on your architecture and RHEL variant - Server/Client...) in output of command `yum repolist`. If it is not there you have to register into RHN Classic (rhn.redhat.com) or your company's Red Hat Satellite or something else - depends on your company's policy.

If you have that channel available, upgrade to `firefox-31.2.0-3.el5_11.x86_64` (which seems to be latest in RHEL5 channel) should be offered.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 3.0.12 is the latest version available in repository of 5.8 and so you are getting same. If you need the latest version then upgrade the OS itself or download the rpm manually and install with `yum localinstall` command.